# URL encode every possible character

Tags: ruby, urlencode

It’s common that I make a request in Ruby that fails because the server doesn’t like the encoding. A common example is having spaces as `+` when the server only understands `%20`. Today I bumped into a server that doesn’t like unencoded hyphens (`-`), requiring `%2D` instead.

I’ve tried `CGI.escape`, `URI.escape`, `ERB::Util.url_encode`, `WEBrick::HTTPUtils.escape`, and none encodes hyphens.

In the past I’ve resorted to `gsub`ing the offending characters as needed, but as I find more servers with more idiosyncrasies, I’d prefer a more stable solution.

Is there a standard (i.e. no external dependencies) approach that percent encodes everything that’s possible?

I’m not looking for just hyphen encoding or `gsub`ing everything one at a time.

Comment: What's your plan for dealing with servers that don't like the _encoded_ form of some characters?

Comment: The W3 specification states: 1) Spaces should be replaced with `+` characters. 2) The characters `*`, `-`, `.`, `0` to `9`, `A` to `Z`, `_` and `a` to `z` can be left as is. 3) Replace all other characters with their percent encoded representation. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URI.escape` was deprecated and replaced by `CGI::escape` which is RFC compliant by grabbing non-alphanum characters and converting them. This is the module that does it:

```
# https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html

# File cgi/util.rb, line 11
def escape(string)
  encoding = string.encoding
  string.b.gsub(/([^ a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/) do |m|
    '%' + m.unpack('H2' * m.bytesize).join('%').upcase
  end.tr(' ', '+').force_encoding(encoding)
end
```

At the end of the day, it's the server that needs fixing, not your code. You can monkeypatch or fork CGI and remove the `-` from the regex, or `gsub()` the character.

Comment: Oh so that's where `URI.escape` ran off to.

Comment: Forking sounds like a much better idea than monkeypatching since you may want to just include this at the application boundry.

Comment: Agreed on the forking approach